# RTSP video record time delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, rtsp

I have very simple code in below, I need to see rtsp video from ip camera. But when I try to run, showing video running very slow.

[image]

Second 11:49:**05** part increase after 3 second around being 11:49:**06**, so I only see 1 second in 3 seconds. It is working very slow. Where is my problem ? How can I solve this.

I check in local ip address video live record. It show very fast and normal.

I install FFmpeg in my system (Windows 10)

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2022-11-03-git-5ccd4d3060-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

And I try also this,

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://[USERNAME]:[PASS]@192.168.1.64/1',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

And nothing has changed.

This is simple code:

```
   import cv2
        
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://[USERNAME]:[PASS]@192.168.1.64/1')
        # cv2.CAP_FFMPEG
        
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            # frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
        
            if not ret: break
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(400) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        cap.release()
        # out.release() # saved
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**DEBUG WITH FFMPEG**

When I working with below code in cmd, I have same issue

```
ffplay -i  rtsp://[PRIVATE]:[PRIVATE]@192.168.1.64/Streaming/Channels/1
```

But when I working with this:

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer rtsp://[PRIVATE]:[PRIVATE]@192.168.1.64/Streaming/Channels/1
```

There is no time delay, how can I add `-fflags nobuffer` commands in opencv code ?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to decrease the number in the cv2.waiyKey from 400 to 1. 
cv2.waitKey(1). tell me if it works.